# Got an error when tried to add new element into array state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and wanted to add new data into array state but faced an error:

> Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

```
 getTitle(title) {
    axios
      .get(
        `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${title}&APPID=7ad09d078633b652ecef8587a337639e&units=metric`
      )
      .then(res => {
        // this.setState({ title: res.data.city });
        this.setState(prevState => {
          title: [...prevState.title, res.data.list]; //Here I get the error
        });
      });
  }
```

Comment: I think prevState.title and res.data.list should be array in order to use spread operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setState` needs to return an object representing the new state.  Quickest fix is to wrap the body of that arrow function in parentheses:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  title: [...prevState.title, res.data.list],
}));
```

Now it's returning a json object

Comment: thanks Danny for your kind reply, I have a question, after we add new data into title array then how can we access it. Like this? {this.state.title[0].name} if so I get an error saying Cannot read property 'name' of undefined. Thank you:)

Comment: Not sure, it could be a few things.  Theoretically, yes, that would work.  But I'd need more context to answer

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to return, try this:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
    title: [...prevState.title, res.data.list] //Here I get the error
}))
```